# Как найти дискорд тег человека, ник которого ты уже знаешь?

Tags: python, discord

Мне нужно найти друга в дискорде при том что я знаю только его никнейм, можете написать код в python для того чтобы подобрать тэг?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Держи:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
            for n in range(10):
                print(f'NAME#{i}{j}{k}{n}')
```

Это все тэги. [`client.get_user_info`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) для поиска.
Только там с этим ником может быть сколько угодно людей ;)